# confused with template class in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I know that the template class definitions is like:

```
template <class TYPE>
class cars{
   public:
   TYPE myCar;
}
```

but somewhere I encountered to this piece of code:

```
template <class T>
class polynomialT {

    ...

}
************************************** 
class GFNUM2m {

...
}
**************************************
template class polynomialT<GFNUM2m>;
```

the last line is vague for me? any one knows what's up? is it an object of polynomialT class?(it seems not because it has no name) is it template?(it seems a duplicate because it has been templated once)

Answer (score 5):

```
template class polynomialT<GFNUM2m>;
```

Is a request to explicitly instantiate the template class `polynomialT` with `GFNUM2m`, including instantiating all its non-template functions.

Some cases when this is needed are:

- When you want to avoid multiple template instantiation (that then get purged by the linker);
- When you want to make sure that the full template can be instantiated even for those (non-template) functions not called;
- When you want to provide template definitions within a .cpp file;

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: When you want to avoid multiple template instantiation (that then get purged by the linker); when you want to make sure that the full template can be instantiated even for those functions not called; when you want to provide template definitions within a *.cpp* file; and probably some other cases...

Comment: This is potentially very useful, I'm surprised I never came across it before.

Answer (score 1):

the last line is equivalent to:

```
class polynomialT {
  protected:
  GFNUM2m *coeff;                   // array of coefficients (? see below)
  int degree;
  ...

}
```

`GFNUM2m *coeff` is not an array, is simply a pointer to a `GFNUM2m` variable. Array and pointer are linked in some way, for example you can allocate dynamically an array with `coeff = new GFNUM2m[10]`, but it is discouraged.

Comment: yes, but it's more like a forward declaration of a type that is used some lines after

Comment: Dynamically allocating arrays isn't discouraged, it's absolutely necessary in some situations... Only discouraged when unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is _explicit template instantiation. Use this to get the compiler to generate all (non-nested-template) members of the template class. This is convenient sometimes when linking externally to templated code, to prevent duplication of object code or missing externals (when methods get inlined).

Template specializations seem similar, but require `template<>` to announce the specialization of an already-declared template. Also, they would define an alternative class definition for that specific template parameter (as @rerun mentions).

Now, on the crosspoint of those, you could see

```
template<> class polynomialT<GFNUM2m>;
```

Which *IS*, in fact, a **forward declared** template **specialization**. This would serve to *prevent* the compiler from auto-instantiating the class template for that type parameter during the rest of the translation unit.

Comment: Template specializations have `<...>` after `template`.

Comment: @K-ballo: Hey I guess I worked out some useful extra information from that confusion. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The last line is a forward declaration of the `polynomialT` class template with a template parameter of `GFNUM2m`, which also instantiates the template class.

Answer (score -2):

it means template in the class polynomialT is now GFNUM2m class.

Comment: i beg your pardon? that is even vaguer to me.

Comment: I mean it's forward decleration for polynomialT's template data member. So we can create a polynomialT object which has a instance of GFNUM2m..

Comment: I'm sorry  but that's  just inaccurate. The whole idea of a forward declaration is to name an incomplete type. In this case, it rather _instantiates_ a _complete_ type (from the clas template). -1